# Declaring delegates when using ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I am trying to figure out how to declare my delegates without getting any errors. I realize now that delegates are supposed to have a weak reference, I was prior to this using **(strong)** refrencing which is obviously a bad thing...

So now I am declaring my delegates like this

class.h

```
//..
id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewdelegate;
//..
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewdelegate;
```

however in my class.m where I have **@synthesize**'d them I am getting this error.

> Existing ivar 'SearchViewdelegate' for __weak property
>   'SearchViewdelegate' must be __weak

So how am I supposed to declare this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `@interface` when you declare the ivar for `SearchViewDelegate`, you need to declare the ivar as weak too:

```
__weak id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewDelegate;
```

Comment: ledgen. I thought I was going crazy. thanks for that it fixed the issue I was having. I'll accept this answer once the time is up.